# Rails- index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok, I am trying to make an instagram clone but the problem is that when I create a post it doesn't accept the title and on the index page it should display the title but it displays the pic_id here is the code on the index page

```
-@pics.each do |pic|
  %h2= link_to pic.title, pic
  = link_to "Gram it", new_pic_path
```

Comment: Does *doesn't accept the title* mean that a newly created pics doesn't have an title stored in the database? Or does it have an title in the database, but doesn't render that title correctly? How does your controller and your form`s view look like?

Comment: Yea I checked the database and it does have a "title" column but yea I think it doesn't render correctly. You think the problem is the form and the controller?

Comment: Okay, the database table has a `title` column, but is something stored in that column or is the column empty? If it is blank, then the problem is in your form or your controller (`create` method or parameter handling).

Answer (score 0):

only to test, try inspect the pic object to be sure that title is filled right:

```
<% @pics.each do |pic| %>
<%= pic.inspect %>
<% end %>
```